# Are the Pearson and Spearman rank correlation coefficients related in a specific way for uniform RVs?

Tags: st.statistics

Are the Pearson and Spearman rank correlation coefficients related in a specific way for uniform random variables? Specifically, is the relationship $\rho_{spearman} = 2*\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}\rho_{pearson})$? If so, why?

Comment: This is a very specific formula that you are asking about, so I don't quite understand the purpose of the question. Is this a formula that you have derived and would like checked, or a formula that you have seen and whose derivation you find unclear? A little more detail on what you know and don't know thus far would be helpful.

Comment: I came across an unsupported statement of the claim by an unreputable source as part of a method to obtain a specified correlation coefficient between two U(0,1) RVs.

Comment: http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=26&threadid=61763&STARTPAGE=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula is from Pearson 1907, see e.g.

Rank Correlation and Product-Moment Correlation
Author(s): P. A. P. Moran
Source: Biometrika, Vol. 35, No. 1/2 (May, 1948), pp. 203-206

Johan

Answer (score 0):

This is only valid for normal distribution.